# Server Side Render React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ssr

На текущий момент мой стек:
Frontend: React (typescript) (create-react-app сборщик)
Backend:  Node.js (typescript (tsc, ts-node)) на Express

Как мне использовать SSR при этой конфигурации?

Пытался и отдельный webpack писать для бэка с притягиванием фронта и различные модули использовать с npm. Либо ничего не работает, либо у меня не получается

Подскажите куда смотреть по этому вопросу

Comment: мне кажется, этот вопрос решается поиском документации по react-ssr. Думаю там должны быть соответствуюзие примеры

Comment: перейти на next.js  -_-

Answer (score 0):

Могу посоветовать следущий курс https://coursehunter.net/course/udemy-server-side-rendering-react-and-redux